# As well as only disabling hyperlinks, also removing hyperlinks string from text document

Tags: html

I have a huge text document. I want to remove hyperlinks strings from my text document. I have viewed many articles regarding this but they only tell to enable or disable the hyperlinks.

My need is not only disabling hyperlinks but also removing hyperlinks string from text document.

Comment: HTML is a markup language, not a scripting language. What are we working with here?

Answer (score 0):

Try running a script that uses regex.  Here's a javascript implementation:

```
var regex = /https?:\/\/(.+?) /g;
textDocument = textDocument.replace(regex, "");
```

Comment: That regex doesn't match half the URLs out there. Mathias Bynens made a nice post about it once. Use a regex from there instead. https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex